# iPhone/iOS automation and UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, automated-tests, ios-frameworks

I've been working with FoneMonkey for iPhone automation, and have been having issues getting the framework to detect taps with `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Does anyone have any experience working with `UIGestureRecognizer` objects with any iOS automation framework, either FoneMonkey or any other framework?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not use included UIAutomation?